# String types not allowed (at 'android:importantForAccessibility' with value 'noHideDescendants')

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to integrate Twitter Login into my app using their Fabric sdk.

My app's requirements for `minSDKVersion`, `targetSDKVersion` and `compileSDKVersion` is `17`. I've gone through the wizard that the Android Studio plugin provides and when I build the project, I get the following error...

```
Error:(107, 56) String types not allowed (at 'android:importantForAccessibility' with value 'noHideDescendants').
```

I see that `noHideDescendants` is a valid value for `importantForAccessibility` in [Android's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:importantForAccessibility)

The error comes from intermediate build files of Twitter SDK for a style named `tw__CompactAttributionLine` in their `values.xml`.

Anybody knows a way of fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

public static final int IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS

Added in API level 19
The view is not important for accessibility, nor are any of its descendant views.

Constant Value: 4 (0x00000004)

ref : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: So I guess you are implying that I build it against API level 19. That means I'll lose some user base, which is bad!